# On $.each pass object in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with passing object to a function and append to a page. Is it really necessary to use prototype? From this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) helped me to understand a bit, but still no success.

on my `$.each`, will add some markers by server and thoses markers will have a link go to a page to give a `description` about the place. the `x` is my object and description is that I want to append it.

```
$.each(data, function (i, x) {
    var alerts = '<button type="button" onclick="getInfo(' + x + ')">AAAA YEAHHH</button>';
}

function getInfo(x) {
...//go to a page and append it
    $('#about-info').append(x.description);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what `data` parameter is structured like?

Comment: Can you the structure? And JSON is just a string, not an object format.  Have you decoded the JSON before trying to pass it to this function?

Comment: [{"id":1,"description":"new york city"}]

Comment: And you are sure `data` is not a JSON string rather than an array of objects? In context of x being an object, your `onclick` decalration makes no sense.  You should probably be attaching an event handler to the button, not writing in-line javascript here.

Comment: it's giving me [Object] [object]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach the click handler like this instead:

```
$.each(data, function (i, x) {
    $('<button type="button">AAAA YEAHHH</button>').on('click', function () {
        getInfo(x);
    }).appendTo('body');
}
```

*OR*

Since you know the property is *x.description* just you the value directly like this

```
$.each(data, function (i, x) {
    var alerts = '<button type="button" onclick="getInfo(\'' + x.description + '\');">AAAA YEAHHH</button>';
}
```

### *An Explanation of `\'' + x.description + '\'`*

Well

- `... \'` is escaping the single quote so that it can be included as a literal value in the javascript string that you're creating.
- The next single quote ends the string that was originally started `'<button ...`.
- `+ x.description +` is concatenating the value of the description property - we're not passing x or a reference of x.description into *getInfo* but instead calling *getInfo* with whatever *x.description* contains at the time the string assigned to *alerts* was created.
- `'\' ...` Here the first single quote starts a new string and then as the first character of that string includes a single quote as a literal value (ie escaping the single quote like this `\'`)

In javascript you can use either double or single quotes to create strings so as an alternative you could have done this

```
var alerts = "<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"getInfo('" + x.description + "');\">AAAA YEAHHH</button>";
```

but again since we're using double quotes to create our string we have to escape the double quotes that we want to include in the string like this `\"`

Comment: The second option is that I'm looking for, and can you give me an explanation the format? of `\'' + x.description + '\'`?

Comment: @fsi it common in most languages http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#JavaScript - html has a different way of doing it though for example you use `&lt;` to show `<`

Comment: What if I want to pass the object? not only description. I have to use the 2nd option? Even though I don't use the append, but google maps to  show button

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build the html button element with code.

```
$.each(data, function(i, x) {
    var localx = x,
        btn = $('<button/>').attr('type','button').click(function(){
            getInfo(localx);
        }).text('AAAA YEAHHH');
    // add btn to the page somewhere here
});

function getInfo(x) {
    $('#about-info').append(x.description);
}
```